# Deploying Site.com Component is failing with error

Tags: community, lightning-community

I am trying to deploy site.com component from Salesforce Sandbox to Production and its failing with following error:

```
We couldn't validate componentAttributes in communityname/themes/customerService.json for component b0349df8-c9e7-4995-bb13-c230c06fc0ec. Error: attribute [crossObjectTypeaheadApiNames]: Invalid value [ManagedContentVersion]. Check your file and try again.
```

I deployed all the Components which the Community pages were referring to. Also, I tried following the steps from the known bug https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001Sp12QAC, with no success, though it was with respect to deploying navigation menu.